# How do I use labels for a set of dynamically created radio buttons?

Tags: vuejs2

I've got a dynamically created radio button list in Vuejs 2:

```
<div class="form-check" v-for="design in designs" :key="design.id">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" :value="design" v-model="selectedDesign" :id="design.id" :name="design.id">
                    <label class="form-check-label" v-bind:for="design.id">{{design.name}}</label>
                  </div>
```

however, that "v-bind:for" doesn't work -- and hardcoding a "for" wouldn't let me link to the dynamically created radio button.
Does anyone know how to use a "for" in a dynamically created label?

Comment: This seems like a very broad question, anyway try to get a reference for each dynamically created radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your snippet works.

Double check your elements' ids, you probably have duplicated ids, causing the `label`s to malfunction.

Check the demo below. There are two radios that work (so you know your snippet works) and one that doesn't (because there is a duplication: a `<div>` with the same `id` of the radio).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    designs: [
      {id: 1, name: "I'm the label for the radio with id=1 (will work)"},
      {id: 2, name: "I'm the label for the radio with id=2 (won't work because another element with id=2 exists)"},
      {id: 3, name: "I'm the label for the radio with id=3 (will work)"}
    ],
    selectedDesign: null
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div id="2">I am a div with id=2.</div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="form-check" v-for="design in designs" :key="design.id">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" :value="design" v-model="selectedDesign" :id="design.id" :name="design.id">
    <label class="form-check-label" v-bind:for="design.id">{{design.name}}</label>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, that was it! I had a duplicate id somewhere else in the page, and it was causing an issue.
Thanks!